# Cannot watch value in component (even using $set) in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a checkbox component which looks like this (I omit html/styles):

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        required: true,
        type: Boolean
      },

      label: {
        required: false,
        type: String
      },

      disabled: {
        required: false,
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },

    data() {
      return {
        isChecked: this.value
      }
    },

    methods: {
      onChange() {
        this.$emit('input', this.isChecked)
      },

      onFocus(event) {
        this.isActive = true
        this.$emit('focus', event)
      },

      onBlur(event) {
        this.isActive = false
        this.$emit('blur', event)
      }
    },

    computed: {
      classes() {
        return [
          { 'is-checked':  this.isChecked },
          { 'is-disabled': this.disabled }
        ];
      }
    },

    watch: {
      value: {
        handler: function(value) {
          console.log('value watcher')
          this.isChecked = !!value
        },
        deep: true,
        immediate: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In another component I have a list of citizens which is an array of objects. So I render it and when user does some action I need to programmatically set the checkbox value.

Here what it looks like:

```
      deselectSelectedCitizen() {
        let index   = this.foreignCitizensCopy.findIndex(citizen => citizen.id === this.selectedCitizen.id)
        let citizen = _.cloneDeep(this.foreignCitizensCopy.find(citizen => citizen.id === this.selectedCitizen.id))
        citizen.checked = false

        // Here I tried different methods, like
        // let citizen = this.foreignCitizensCopy.find(citizen => citizen.id === this.selectedCitizen.id)
        // this.$set(citizen, 'checked', false)

        // This one is just rough changing of array
        this.foreignCitizensCopy.splice(index, 1)
        this.foreignCitizensCopy.push(citizen)


        // Also tried to use $set both for "citizen" and for the whole array, updating object
        // this.$set(this.foreignCitizensCopy, index, citizen)


        // In any cases the array did changed, but it does not call checkbox's watcher
        console.log(_.cloneDeep(this.foreignCitizensCopy))

        this.selectedCitizen = null
      },
```

So I tried different methods and in all cases the `checked` attribute in the `foreignCitizensCopy` array changed, however the watcher in my checkbox component did not fire.

I suspect something's wrong with checkbox but couldn't not figure out what exactly

Comment: need to see how you are using the checkbox component

Comment: Why do you use `_.cloneDeep` ?

Comment: How `citizen.checked` is connected with your checkbox component ?